# Django form prefix separator hyphen to underscore

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-formtools

The naming process for `django-formtools` seems to be breaking the ability to access variables in session data.

The form I have named patient_details but it's fields are being separated by - for example `patient_details-upper_arch`. I'm trying to access the session data to manipulate a form further along in the wizard based on a selection in the first form. However when trying to access `{{ ...patient_details-upper_arch }}` it throws a `TemplateSyntaxError` `Could not parse the remainder: '-upper_arch' from ...patient_details-upper_arch`

Is there a way to set the separator to an underscore to make this variable accessible in the template, or another way around this?

Comment: I know there is a naming error. It's something that is caused by the `django-formtools` library not something I have done. I'm looking for a solution to get around this because I didn't name the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this with a simple_tag custom tag.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_session_formwizard_variable(session, key):
    return session.get(key, '')
```